# Adding xml:lang to MVC XDocument

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

How to add `xml:lang="en"` to xElement?
I am getting an error:

**"The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name"**

```cs
XDocument objXDoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("cXml",
        new XAttribute("xml:lang", "en")
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute "xml:lang" must be set like this:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en")
```

Since the "xml" namespace is a default one, the XNamespace that represents it is provided as a static property on the XNamespace class itself.

Further reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "lang", "en");
```